# Change volume with Dell Latitude point stick buttons

Tags: batch-file, dell-latitude

I have a dell Latitude with point stick and buttons that I never use. The keyboard also does not have volume controls, even via the function key. What I want to do is map the three point stick buttons to volume - down/mute/up respectively. The Dell touchpad control panel does give me options to customize these buttons, but it's a bit limited. These are my options:
[image]

As you can see, there is a `Run` option, which I can use to select a file to open, shortcut to open, or exe/bat file to run. So my first inkling is to use that to run a batch command that will lower/mute/raise the volume. How can I achieve this with a batch file? Alternatively, how can I do this without the batch file option?

Answer (score 0):

Searching around, I found this script in a few places (so I don't rightly know who to credit)

script to toggle the mute status of volume control:

```
set WshShell=createobject("wscript.shell")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.run "sndvol32"
WshShell.AppActivate "Volume Control"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}{TAB}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys(" ")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.AppActivate "Volume Control"
WshShell.sendkeys "%{f4}"
```